# How can an app developer prevent the app store from auto updating the app in certain conditions?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, auto-update

I would like to know if there is a way for an iOS and Android app developer to prevent the appstore from automatically updating the app on the user's device, under certain conditions.

The app would make some internal checks & tests and keep ignoring the updates until the test result becomes positive.

Would something like this be possible in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen (mostly games) download extra data updates inside the apps, which is I suppose a form of updating that you could control, but it's obviously somewhat limited. For iOS, there is also https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process , and as far as I could find that's it. (no clue on the android side)